# What size should a business card be to fit snugly into a 3.5x2.25" sleeve?

Tags: print-design

A client requested a new design for business cards that also have a protective paper sleeve like these: http://www.envelopes.com/business/open-end/credit-card-sleeve-envelopes

Since i've never done this before, i thought it would be good to ask first, what dimensions should the business card be in order to fit exactly in a 3.5x2inches sleeve?

Comment: Those sleeves are designed to fit the standard card size, so you really shouldn't need any adjustment. You don't want it "snug" because then it'll be impossible to pull out.

Comment: I will be designing the sleeves and the business card, so what i am looking for is how much difference between those 2 designs should be in inches

Comment: Can't you buy some and reverse-engineer them?

Comment: I'd simply use the size of the link you posted, 1/4" larger for the sleeve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are designing both card and sleeve, you should keep the card standard size of 3.5 x 2. This way it will fit in other standard places your client may want to use it, such as the slits on a pocket folder.

Designing the sleeve with an additional 1/8 inch on the short dimension should keep the sleeve fairly snug while allowing the card to slide, but this would also depend on the weight of the paper you are using. (The link you referred to shows dimensions 1/8 larger than a standard credit card.) I would suggest asking your printer to build you a dummy with the actual paper stocks so you can be sure.